# Covariance of 2 Shortest Pieces in Broken Stick

Tags: probability

I can't get to the end of this problem without getting confused about my own computations. Perhaps someone could help?

Problem:
A stick of length 1 is broken uniformly. Then the smaller piece is broken uniformly. What is the Covariance of the resulting 2 pieces?

In fact this problem is posed here exactly:
[A stick of unit length is cut into three pieces of lengths $X, Y, Z$ according to its length in two sequence of cuts. Find Cov(X,Y).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618705/a-stick-of-unit-length-is-cut-into-three-pieces-of-lengths-x-y-z-according-t#)

I found some work there, but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Please don't deliberately duplicate questions. It's OK to ask specific questions about other questions, e.g. about parts of an answer you don't understand, but here you didn't do that, you just repeated the question. I'll be answering the other question and then closing this one as a duplicate.

Comment: For future reference -- how do I get people to look at old unanswered posts?

Comment: It just so happens that if you look at the yellow box "hot meta posts" in the sidebar on the right there's currently a trending question [What to do if my question is already made?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23178). The only existing answer proposes to do what you did. It got $14$ upvotes and $4$ downvotes, so it looks like I'm in the minority on this. However, the same principles apply as to any other question; see [How to as a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and in particular the section "Include your work".

Comment: If you include your work and show us where you got stuck, then you're not just reasking the old question; you're asking more specifically about how to make progress on it using a particular approach and getting stuck in a particular place. In the process, you might be contributing to the old question finally getting answered.

Comment: This prompted me to write [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23268) to the question on meta.